# SelectDirectory/ShBrowseForFolder issue when having a lot of shell items

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-shell

I'm running into a very strange problem with the Vcl.FileCtrl function **SelectDirectory**  (which is a thin wrapper around the **ShBrowseForFolder** Win32 API).

I'm using the following code to allow the user to browse for a file or a folder:

```
  if SelectDirectory('Sélectionnez un élément à ajouter :', '', S, [sdNewFolder,
    sdShowFiles, sdNewUI]) then
```

When executing this code, the "Browse for folder" dialog is correctly shown, displaying the content of the user's Desktop:

[image: SelectDirectory with less than 100 desktop files]

But when the number of items in the Desktop folder is excessively large (on my computer, I can reproduce the problem by having approx. 100 desktop icons), the same call produces a totally different display:

[image: SelectDirectory with more than 100 desktop files]

In this case, the Desktop items aren't shown anymore. I'm only allowed to explore my home folder and since I've lost the "My Computer" icon I cannot select a file/folder outside of this directory.

I'm searching what I'm missing here. Is there a limit in the number of subitems a root item can have for a correct display? Having a lot of desktop icons is certainely not a good practice, but as far as I know that shouldn't prevent this dialog to operate normally. I'm not sure if there is something wrong in the Delphi wrapper, or if that's a limitation of the API I didn't see on MSDN...

Any hint appreciated!

Comment: I see the same with the same API call from VB6. Any more than 97 sub objects of "Desktop" and it just shows the user's profile folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround I came to is to use the "old" (Win XP) UI, which can be done by not specifying the `[sdNewUI]` flag. In this case, all the items are correctly displayed.

That seems to be the only valid solution when the user must select files OR folders, something `TFileOpenDialog` is not capable of.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, I can reproduce this behaviour. It's clearly a Windows limitation and the API in question does not offer you any way to increase buffers. I think your chances of working around it using `SHBrowseForFolder` are close to zero. Because `SHBrowseForFolder` is now a a legacy API.

If you are browsing for folders then you should use `IFileOpenDialog` in folder selection mode. That's a  a much nicer dialog that uses the new Vista dialogs. In Delphi that is wrapped by `TFileOpenDialog`. Only use that if `Win32MajorVersion>=6` though! For XP you need to call back on `SHBrowseForFolder`.

```
if Win32MajorVersion>=6 then
begin
  FileOpenDialog1.Title := 'Sélectionnez un élément à ajouter :';
  FileOpenDialog1.Options := FileOpenDialog1.Options + [fdoPickFolders];
  if FileOpenDialog1.Execute then
    Beep;
end else
begin
  // revert to SelectDirectory
end;
```

Comment: Why is `SHBrowseForFolder` 'legacy'? It's a nice, perfcetly working GUI in my opinion.

Comment: It's legacy because of `IFileDialog`. That's how new apps are meant to do it. The documentation for `SHBrowseForFolder` says so.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed I already tested the FileOpenDialog component, but it seems that I cannot select both files AND folders through this dialog. That has been apparently reported to MS :  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsuidevelopment/thread/4a330e26-4d52-4fce-8a89-5c56fa132688

Comment: Ah, I had not spotted that nuance. In which case I think you are stuck.

Comment: An interesting remark : with the "old" version of the dialog (without specifying [sdNewUI] or BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE), the bug does not appear. Weird...